# How to find the slope of a secant line when $ y=\ln x$???

Tags: calculus

Let $y=\ln x$.  Find the slope of the secant line between $P=(5, \ln5)$ and $Q=(9, \ln9)$.

Should I just replace $\ln x$ with any of those two points? Ex: $y=\ln9$ or $y=\ln5$??

Please Help!!

Comment: For **any** function $f(x)$, if $a\ne b$ then $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ is the slope of the secant line joining $P=(a,f(a))$ to $Q=(b,f(b))$. In our case, we get $\frac{\ln(9)-\ln(5)}{9-5}$, which may be "simplified" in various ways. That is probably what you meant by "replace."

Comment: Just apply the slope fomula rise over run. You do not need the function anymore since the line is determined by its two points. The reason why it is called a secant is because it intersects y = lnx rather than being a tangent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the slope of the secant line between two points is just a fancy way of being asked to apply the usual [slope formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope#Definition) of rise over run to two points. Hence, we obtain:
$$
\dfrac{\ln 9 - \ln 5}{9 - 5}
$$